# How do I turn each page of a word document into its own document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document with 100 pages. Each page represents unique text. I want to 'split' each page into its own document and save it with the filename of whatever is on the first line of that page. Any idea how I would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each page has a heading, you can split the document into "[Subdocuments](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051869301033.aspx)"

Alternatively, you could try a macro - if you search google for [split word document](http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en___CA357&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=split+word+document) there are several different macros which appear to work.